# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2020 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://sports.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 9):

This seems an appropriate time to announce that I am not seeking election.

I've been a member of Sports.SE since day 1, and had the privilege and responsibility of serving as a moderator since the first set were appointed back in early 2012.

It was generally understood at the time that pro-tem moderatorship on a Stack Exchange site was a temporary thing, rarely lasting more than a year. I had in fact already served on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com) from beginning until the site's graduation, which took a mere 7 months.

So my serving here for 8 years (!) is something of an accident.

I haven't been able to spend much time on the site for quite a while now, only jumping on to clear the moderation queue once in a blue moon. And I haven't really been keeping track of Meta at all.

I've appreciated the energy that first edmastermind29 and now Philip Kendall have shown as fellow moderators. And I was going to credit Philip with moderating for about a year, when in fact he's been going at it since 2017, which shows that I am not paying the site nearly the attention it deserves and needs. Sorry Philip!

I wish the elected moderators all the best. I'll still be around, and if American sports come back, I hope to join the March Madness bracket challenge once again next year.

Farewell!

Comment: Thanks for your (apparently unexpected!) years of service - you've contributed a great deal to this site, and it's much appreciated!  (And, look forward to the bracket challenge!  Not sure the odds of it happening in 2021, but we'll have an NCAA tournament _someday_ ...)

Comment: And thank you for your service to the site.